# Laravel 5 M2M Polymorphic relations not setting?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

Here's the basic code:

```
/**
 * Post.php
 */
class Post extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    public function tags() {
        return $this->morphToMany('Tag', 'taggable', 'taggable_taggables')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}

/**
 * Tag.php
 */
class Tag extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    protected $table = 'taggable_tags';

    public function taggable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Now take the following code:

```
// assume that both of these work (i.e. the models exist)
$post = Post::find(1);
$tag = Tag::find(1);

$post->tags()->attach($tag);
```

So far so good.  The relationship is being created in the `taggable_taggables` pivot table.  However, if I immediately do:

```
dd($post->tags);
```

It returns an empty collection. `attach()` seems to create the relationship in the *database* but not in the current instance of the model.

This can be checked by loading the model again:

```
$post = Post::find(1);
dd($post->tags);
```

And now the relationship is hydrated.

I'm pretty sure this worked in Laravel 4.2 -- i.e. the relationship was updated immediately after `attach()`.  Is there anyway to nudge Laravel 5 into doing the same thing?

Comment: I am now not so sure this worked in Laravel 4.2. But I'm still wondering if Laravel (4.2 and/or 5) can be nudged into doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel will only load the relationship attribute once, whether it is eager loaded or lazy loaded.  That means that once the attribute has been loaded, any changes to the relationship will not be reflected by the attribute unless the relationship is explicitly reloaded.

The exact code you posted should have worked as expected, so I'm assuming there is a piece that is missing.  For example:

```
$post = Post::find(1);
$tag = Tag::find(1);

$post->tags()->attach($tag);

// This should dump the correct data, as this is the first time the
// attribute is being accessed, so it will be lazy loaded right here.
dd($post->tags);
```

Versus:

```
$post = Post::find(1);
$tag = Tag::find(1);

// access tags attribute here which will lazy load it
var_dump($post->tags);

$post->tags()->attach($tag);

// This will not reflect the change from attach, as the attribute
// was already loaded, and it has not been explicitly reloaded
dd($post->tags);
```

To work around this issue, if you need to refresh the relationship attribute, you can use the `load()` method, instead of re-retrieving the parent object:

```
$post = Post::find(1);
$tag = Tag::find(1);

// access tags attribute here which will lazy load it
var_dump($post->tags);

$post->tags()->attach($tag);

// refresh the tags relationship attribute
$post->load('tags');

// This will dump the correct data as the attribute has been
// explicitly reloaded.
dd($post->tags);
```

As far as I know, there are no parameters or settings to force Laravel to refresh the relationship automatically.  I also can't think of a model event that you could hook into, since you're not actually updating the parent model. There are three main options I can think of:

1. Create a method on the model that performs the attach and reload.

   ```
   public function attachTags($tags) {
       $this->tags()->attach($tags);
       $this->load('tags');
   }

   $post = Post::find(1);
   $tag = Tag::find(1);
   $post->attachTags($tag);
   dd($post->tags);
   ```
2. Create a new relationship class that extends the BelongsToMany relationship class and override the `attach` method to perform your desired logic. Then, create a new model class that extends the Eloquent Model class, and override the `belongsToMany` method to create an instance of your new relationship class. Finally, update your Post model to extend your new Model class, instead of the Eloquent Model class.
3. Just make sure to always reload your relationships when you need to.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  I was, indeed, loading the tags before the attach, which would explain why I don't see them until forcing a reload.

In the end, I did what you suggested in your first suggestion: manually run `->load('tags')` after the attaching.